# Instant send feature in quicksilver

Tags: quicksilver, launchbar

I just switched back to quicksilver and I was wondering if there is an instant send feature in QS like Launchbar.

in Launchbar, you can define a hotkey which will send the selected file/folder as a context to launchbar, and you can perform an action on it like open in TextMate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to use the currently *selected thing* (files/folders in finder, selected text in other applications, ...) in Quicksilver.

There is the ⌘⎋ (command-escape) shortcut. It opens the Quicksilver interface with the *selected thing* in the first pane

Or you can open the Quicksilver interface and use the "Current Selection" proxy object. That does the same thing as above, but when the interface is already active. For that, you need to activate "Enable advanced features" in Preferences -> Application.

Using the "Current Selection" proxy object, you can also make your own triggers that use the thing that's selected at the time you use the trigger. Check out [the Quicksilver Manual](http://mysite.verizon.net/hmelman/Quicksilver.pdf) somewhere around page 38 for more information on that.